# View extending EditText loses Styles and is not focusable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I try to subclass EditText for convenience reasons (NumberEdit) using kotlin but the rendered View loses most of the EditText properties. The look is that of a TextView and it is not focusable with the mouse (in the emulator). When I click into the activity I can then edit the first of the NumberEdit widgets and can cycle to the next one with the tab key.

I added two emulator screenshots to illustrate the difference.

An EditText looks like this

[image: An EditText looks like this]

The new NumberEdit looks like this

[image: The new NumberEdit looks like this]

The extended class looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.InputType
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.EditText


class EditNumber(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int)
    : EditText(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attributeSet, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
        : this(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, 0)

    init {
        inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? Do I have to reference some attributes explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a kotlin expert but if you look at the java source code for edittext you have following:

```
public class EditText extends TextView {
    public EditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle);
    }
    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }
    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
```

It doesn't look like you pass the right parameters to the constructor... You pass a lot of 0s and nulls...

Comment: Yes, in kotlin all constructors have to call the primary constructor of the class, which is declared in the class signature. And since those other constructors do not have all parameters set that are needed for the primary constructor I have to pass null/0. The EditText constructors do the same with one difference, the two arg constructor passes the hard coded editTextStyle Id. I think this is the problem in my case. Will give it a try later today. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yeap, that solved it. Only difference was that com.android.internal.R could not be resolved but using android.R seems to work as well.

Comment: @Candlejack Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can write this much more concise:

```
class EditNumber @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = R.attr.editTextStyle,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : EditText(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes)
```

Notice the `defStyle` parameter.