# Why does my extended EditText not respond like an EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I created a class that extends EditText and forces them into a square shape with a border. I cannot click on nor edit the text in any of these. When I change the 4 SquareCell views back to EditText views, I am able to edit them (but obviously lose the square format). Why can't I edit SquareCell views?

SquareCell class

```
package com.example.autogrid

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

class SquareCell @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var squareSize = 0f
    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 5f
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        //find smaller dimension between width and height and set layout size to it
        val smallerDim = Math.min(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        )
        super.onMeasure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(smallerDim, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(smallerDim, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        )
        squareSize = smallerDim.toFloat()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        //add border
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, squareSize, squareSize, paint)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.example.autogrid.SquareCell
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Edit Text 00"/>

            <com.example.autogrid.SquareCell
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Edit Text 01"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.example.autogrid.SquareCell
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Edit Text 10"/>

            <com.example.autogrid.SquareCell
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Edit Text 11"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result with SquareCells (not editable):

[image: Result with SquareCells (not editable)]

Result when I use EditTexts (editable but not squares):

[image: Result when I use EditTexts (editable but not squares)]

Comment: Did you saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393628/11538132 ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use that library you can archive these things throw a custom shape, and set that background to editText.

Here is the shape code for reference

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>  
 <stroke android:width="1dp"android:color="#F0F0F0" />
 </shape>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just put a border around the EditText? I am also trying to force it into a square shape...